# Trigger button click event programmatically using JavaScript or jQuery on page load in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have this piece of code

```
window.onload = function () {
    $('#btnFilter').click(function (e) {
        btnFilter(e);
    });
}
```

The function works on button click but I need that the button is clicked when the page opens. I've tried things like $('#btnFilter').trigger( "click" ); but the button still not clicked on page opening. How can I achieve this thing? I can't just call the function because I get the error "Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of undefined" beacuse I don't give any event as parameter.

```
function btnFilter(e) {
    element = e.currentTarget.parentElement;
    //other code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnFilter').trigger('click');
});

$(document).on('click','#btnFilter',function(e){
    btnFilter(e);
});

function btnFilter(e)
{
    element = e.currentTarget.parentElement;
}
```

Comment: This worked. Even if I can't delete the window.onload = function () {} so having $(document).ready(function(){} inside window.onload I think is not a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can change your 'btnFilter' to accept the button instead of the event:

```
function btnFilter(element) {
    element = element.parentElement;
    ...
}

$(function() { 
  $("#btnFilter").click(function(e) { btnFilter(this); return false; });

  // Pass the button to the filter operation on load
  btnFilter($("#btnFilter")[0]);
});
```

alternatively, accept the parent element directly

```
$(function() { 
  $("#btnFilter").click(function(e) { btnFilter(this.parentElement); return false; });

  // Pass the button parent to the filter operation on load
  btnFilter($("#btnFilter")[0].parentElement);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery i would keep it coherent and not mix it with vanilla javascript. A Jquery solution is:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnFilter", btnFilter);
$(document).ready(function(){$("#btnFilter").click()});
```

or

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnFilter", btnFilter);
$(document).ready(btnFilter);
```

In you solution the error is the event binding: when you bind the event to `#btnFilter` on page load, the element is not existing yet, so the function cannot be triggered.

Answer (score -1):

**jQuery Solution:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").trigger("click");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="alert('clicked')">Click</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For IE backward compatibility issue add following in header tag - <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">